# url rewriting for .php extension to .aspx in IIS

Tags: php, asp.net, windows, iis

I have a PHP website in IIS 8.5 running on Windows Server 2012. I need to change one of its URLs (ending with .php extension) to .aspx. For more clarification, say my site is www.abc.com and I need to rewrite a page www.abc.com/test.php into www.abc.com/test.aspx.

How to do this?

Comment: You want to rewrite the PHP as ASP? Either find a tool to do it (seems doubtful, but I don't know), or just start writing ASP, using the PHP as a guide. Or are you trying to edit the file name requested in the URL? `.htaccess` can do that.

Answer (score 1):

You want to create a handler mapping to make ASP.NET handler response for request which end with `.php`. When you click handler mappings on IIS, you can find some handler mappings named "PageHandlerFactory-xxx" and their paths are "`.aspx`"(ASP.NET role service is required here). You can create the handler mappings with the same Handler except different path "`.php`".